# Problem to understand the internal potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

I am reading Goldstein, at the page eleven, he is deriving what he called later the internal potential energy of a body.

He made so three equality:

Let ${\bf r}_i$ be the position of $i$ particle

Let ${\bf r}_j$ be the position of the $j$ particle

Let ${\bf r}_{ij} = {\bf r}_i - {\bf r}_j$

$$\nabla_{i}V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij}V_{ij} = -\nabla_{j}V_{ij}$$

Where $V$ is a potential energy function. I am missing the second term here. The first be equal to the third is basically the third Newton's law, but why should it be equal to the second term?

Comment: please provide a photo to the context you are talking about as everyone always not follow the same books

Comment: @Anonymous Actually pictures are not accessible to all users. It is much better to type out the text. If you want more context you should ask the OP to type out more of the context rather than posting pictures of the text.

Comment: @BioPhysicist even that would work out

Answer (score 2):

The third term is indirectly related to Newton's third law, but is directly related to the definition of $\mathbf r_{ij}=\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j$. If the potential function has this form for all $(i,j)$ pairs then Newton's third law will hold. But the reason we pick up the negative sign in the third term is just due to the chain rule.

The same thing is true for the second term. Since $V_{ij}=V(\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j)=V_{ij}(\mathbf r_{ij})$, we must have that $\nabla_iV_{ij}=\nabla_{ij}V_{ij}$ by the chain rule.

As a simpler example, let's say I have a function $f=f(x,y)$ that takes the form $f(x,y)=f(x-y)=f(z)$ for $z=x-y$ Then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\text d f}{\text d z}\cdot\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\text d f}{\text d z}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\text d f}{\text d z}\cdot\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac{\text d f}{\text d z}$$

So we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\text d f}{\text d z}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Copy this example two more times and condense into vector notation to get what you are asking about.